# A better way to define types to produce nested JSON

Tags: json, go

I need to produce the following JSON output using Go.

```
{
  "id": "zx222",
  "links": {
    "main_entity": {
      "data": [{
        "type": "car",
        "id": "abc123"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

The straightforward way to generate the above JSON via marshaling would be using the following types

```
type Element struct{
  Id    string      `json:"id"`
  Links LinksObject `json:"links"`
}

type LinksObject struct{
  MainEntity MainEntityObject `json:"main_entity"`
}

type MainEntityObject struct{
  Data []EntityDef `json:"data"`
}

type EntityDef struct{
  Type string `json:"type"`
  Id   string `json:"id"`
}
```

Is there a better way to generate the above JSON without defining each struct just to nest the structure?

Adding some of my thoughts behind the question. The original JSON has extra nested levels due to how the messages are wrapped. But they do not necessarily carry any significance otherwise and defining them as data types just for decoding/encoding to JSON seems unnecessary.

Comment: You could define all of them as nested anonymous structs but I wouldn't consider that "better". What is your concern with the working implementation you have?

Comment: If you want to see the version with anonymous structs, dump your JSON into this: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: @Adrian there is no concern as such. I am new to GO and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: @Adrian that link was helpful. I did not know about anonymous structs. Thank you.

Comment: the rule of thumb: if you're only using this in one place ([see slides 2, 3 & 4](https://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#2)), use anonymously defined structs; more than once define a reusable type.

Comment: @colminator makes sense. The reason I also asked this question is because the original JSON structure has the nesting that is not a reusable structure and is used only in that specific case. Thank you for linking the presentation.

Comment: for configs (only loaded at program init time) - I often define anonymous structs - as its only ever populated via a YAML file input - and the struct types would never be used (or rather reused) anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

```
type Element struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Links struct {
        MainEntity struct {
            Data []struct {
                Type string `json:"type"`
                ID   string `json:"id"`
            } `json:"data"`
        } `json:"main_entity"`
    } `json:"links"`
}
```

Comment: Yes this does help reduce the number of type definitions. However, this led to some unfriendly way to initialize part of the struct. But, for now I have solved it by providing a convenience method to improve the usage.